# Building a Airline Database for class project

Tags: sql, oracle

My class project is I have to build Airline database. For some reason only a couple tables are being created CITY, and AIRCRAFT_DATA. I am new to sql in and  I am trying to understand why my other tables are not being created and I keep getting errors.
I fixed the Customer Name for the first table, but I don't know where to begin with the other errors I have encountered.
I am using Oracle SQL 11g

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Customer
  2  (Cust_Nbr VARCHAR(3) Constraint pk_Customer Primary Key NOT NULL,
  3  Cust_Name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
  4  );



Error starting at line : 10 in command -
CREATE TABLE Customer
(Cust_Nbr VARCHAR(3) Constraint pk_Customer Primary Key NOT NULL,
Cust_Name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
)
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE Reservation
  2  (Cust_Nbr VARCHAR2(14),
  3  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Cust_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Nbr)
  4  REFERENCES Customer ,
  5  Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(15), CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Flight_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr)
  6  REFERENCES Flight_Date,
  7  Flight_Date DATE,
  8  CONSTRAINT fk_Sched_Flight_Flight_Date FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Date)
  9  REFERENCES Shed_Flight
 10  );

Error starting at line : 15 in command -
CREATE TABLE Reservation
(Cust_Nbr VARCHAR2(14),
CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Cust_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Nbr)
REFERENCES Customer ,
Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(15), CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Flight_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr)
REFERENCES Flight_Date,
Flight_Date DATE,
CONSTRAINT fk_Sched_Flight_Flight_Date FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Date)
REFERENCES Shed_Flight
)
Error report -
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
02267. 00000 -  "column type incompatible with referenced column type"
*Cause:    The data type or collation of the referencing column was
           incompatible with the data type or collation of the referenced
           column.
*Action:   Select a compatible data type for the referencing column.
           Also, the collation of a character column in a foreign key must
           match the collation of the corresponding column in the primary
           key.
SQL> 
SQL> 


 SQL> CREATE TABLE Shed_Flight
      2  (Flight_Date date Constraint pk_Shed_Flight Primary Key,
      3  Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3),    
      4  CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight_Flight_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr)
      5  REFERENCES FlightData,
      6  Seats_Resvd VARCHAR2(3),
      7  Seat#_Ava VARCHAR2(3),
      8  TOD VARCHAR2(8),
      9  TOA VARCHAR2(8),
     10  Serial# VARCHAR2(10), CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight FOREIGN KEY (Serial#)
     11  REFERENCES AirCraft_Type
     12  );
    
  

  Error starting at line : 27 in command -
    CREATE TABLE Shed_Flight
    (Flight_Date date Constraint pk_Shed_Flight Primary Key,
    Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight_Flight_Nbr FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr)
    REFERENCES FlightData,
    Seats_Resvd VARCHAR2(3),
    Seat#_Ava VARCHAR2(3),
    TOD VARCHAR2(8),
    TOA VARCHAR2(8),
    Serial# VARCHAR2(10), CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight FOREIGN KEY (Serial#)
    REFERENCES AirCraft_Type
    )
    Error report -
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE TABLE FlightData
      2  (Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) Constraint pk_FlightData Primary Key,
      3  Depart_Code VARCHAR2(30),
      4  CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Depart_Code FOREIGN KEY(Depart_Code)
      5  REFERENCES Airport,
      6  Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(30),
      7  CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Ariv_Code FOREIGN KEY(Ariv_Code)
      8  REFERENCES Airport
      9  );
    
    Error starting at line : 41 in command -
    CREATE TABLE FlightData
    (Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) Constraint pk_FlightData Primary Key,
    Depart_Code VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Depart_Code FOREIGN KEY(Depart_Code)
    REFERENCES Airport,
    Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(30),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Ariv_Code FOREIGN KEY(Ariv_Code)
    REFERENCES Airport
    )
    Error report -
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE TABLE Airport
      2  (Airport_Code VARCHAR2(7) Constraint pk_Airport Primary Key,
      3  City_Code VARCHAR2(3), Constraint fk_Airport_City_Code FOREIGN KEY(City_Code)
      4  REFERENCES City, 
      5  Airport_Name VARCHAR2(30)
      6  );
    
    Error starting at line : 51 in command -
    CREATE TABLE Airport
    (Airport_Code VARCHAR2(7) Constraint pk_Airport Primary Key,
    City_Code VARCHAR2(3), Constraint fk_Airport_City_Code FOREIGN KEY(City_Code)
    REFERENCES City, 
    Airport_Name VARCHAR2(30)
    )
    Error report -
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE TABLE AirCraft_Type
      2  (Serial# VARCHAR2(8), Conrtaint pk_AirCraft_Type Primary Key, 
      3  Type_ VARCHAR2(6), CONSTRAINT fk_AirCraft_Type FOREIGN KEY(Type)
      4  REFERENCES AirCraft_Data
      5  );
    
    Error starting at line : 59 in command -
    CREATE TABLE AirCraft_Type
    (Serial# VARCHAR2(8), Conrtaint pk_AirCraft_Type Primary Key, 
    Type_ VARCHAR2(6), CONSTRAINT fk_AirCraft_Type FOREIGN KEY(Type)
    REFERENCES AirCraft_Data
    )
    Error report -
    ORA-00904: "TYPE": invalid identifier
    00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE TABLE Aircraft_Data
      2  (Type_ VARCHAR2(6) Constraint pk_Aircraft_Data Primary Key,
      3  Description_ VARCHAR2(20),
      4  Capacity_ VARCHAR2(3),
      5  Range_ VARCHAR2(4)
      6  );
    
    Table AIRCRAFT_DATA created.
    
    SQL> 
    SQL> 
    SQL> CREATE TABLE City
      2  (City_Code VARCHAR2(3) Constraint pk_City Primary Key,
      3  City_Name VARCHAR2(15),
      4  State_ VARCHAR2(2)
      5  );
    
    Table CITY created.
```

Comment: Can you edit your post in a more organized way, separate codes from errors, and provide some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the tables in the reverse order. You need to create `CITY` before `AIRPORT` and `AIRCRAFT_DATA` before `AIRCRAFT_TYPE` before `AIRPORT` and so on; otherwise, how does the database know what your foreign keys refer to if the table you are referencing does not exist.

You also need to specify which column a foreign key references.

Other than that, you spell `CONSTRAINT` wrong several times and `FLIGHT_DATE` should be `FLIGHTDATA` for `fk_Reservation_Flight_Nbr`.

Apart from that, your data model is flawed as `SHED_FLIGHT` does not allow for 2 flights at the same time as the primary key is only on the `DATE` field.

```sql
CREATE TABLE City (
  City_Code VARCHAR2(3) Constraint pk_City Primary Key,
  City_Name VARCHAR2(15),
  State_ VARCHAR2(2)
);

CREATE TABLE Aircraft_Data (
  Type_ VARCHAR2(6) Constraint pk_Aircraft_Data Primary Key,
  Description_ VARCHAR2(20),
  Capacity_ VARCHAR2(3),
  Range_ VARCHAR2(4)
);

CREATE TABLE AirCraft_Type (
  Serial# VARCHAR2(8) Constraint pk_AirCraft_Type Primary Key, 
  Type_ VARCHAR2(6),
  CONSTRAINT fk_AirCraft_Type
    FOREIGN KEY(Type_) REFERENCES AirCraft_Data (Type_)
);

CREATE TABLE Airport(
  Airport_Code VARCHAR2(7) Constraint pk_Airport Primary Key,
  City_Code VARCHAR2(3),
  Constraint fk_Airport_City_Code
    FOREIGN KEY(City_Code) REFERENCES City ( City_Code ), 
  Airport_Name VARCHAR2(30)
);

CREATE TABLE FlightData(
  Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3) Constraint pk_FlightData Primary Key,
  Depart_Code VARCHAR2(30),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Depart_Code
    FOREIGN KEY(Depart_Code) REFERENCES Airport(Airport_Code),
  Ariv_Code VARCHAR2(30),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Flight_Data_Ariv_Code
    FOREIGN KEY(Ariv_Code) REFERENCES Airport(Airport_Code)
);

CREATE TABLE Shed_Flight (
  Flight_Date date Constraint pk_Shed_Flight Primary Key,
  Flight_Nbr VARCHAR2(3),    
  CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight_Flight_Nbr
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr) REFERENCES FlightData (Flight_Nbr),
  Seats_Resvd VARCHAR2(3),
  Seat#_Ava VARCHAR2(3),
  TOD VARCHAR2(8),
  TOA VARCHAR2(8),
  Serial# VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight
    FOREIGN KEY (Serial#) REFERENCES AirCraft_Type (Serial#)
);

CREATE TABLE Customer(
  Cust_Nbr VARCHAR(3) Constraint pk_Customer Primary Key NOT NULL,
  Cust_Name VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Reservation(
  Cust_Nbr    VARCHAR2(14),
  Flight_Nbr  VARCHAR2(15),
  Flight_Date DATE,
  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Cust_Nbr
    FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Nbr) REFERENCES Customer (Cust_Nbr),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Flight_Nbr
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr) REFERENCES FlightData ( flight_nbr ),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Sched_Flight_Flight_Data
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Date) REFERENCES Shed_Flight ( flight_date )
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=375637380ab9b676456d703f7da5f741)*

## Update

> For Shed_Flight do you have a recommendation on how to able to fix that flawed part of the data model?

Have a composite unique constraint of `flight_nbr` and `flight_date` which will allow flights from different locations to happen on the same date. This could be a composite primary key but I would prefer to have a single auto-generated identity column as the primary key and then that pair of columns as `NOT NULL` and `UNIQUE` so that either the `id` or that pair could be used in a `FOREIGN KEY`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Shed_Flight (
  id          NUMBER(10,0)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT pk_Shed_Flight PRIMARY KEY,
  Flight_Date DATE
              NOT NULL,
  Flight_Nbr  VARCHAR2(3)
              NOT NULL,    
  Seats_Resvd VARCHAR2(3),
  Seat#_Ava   VARCHAR2(3),
  TOD         VARCHAR2(8),
  TOA         VARCHAR2(8),
  Serial#     VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT u_Shed_Flight_Flight_Date_Flight_Nbr
    UNIQUE (Flight_date, Flight_Nbr),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight_Flight_Nbr
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr) REFERENCES FlightData (Flight_Nbr),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Shed_Flight
    FOREIGN KEY (Serial#) REFERENCES AirCraft_Type (Serial#)
);
```

Then you can reference the composite unique key in the `Reservation` table (and add in `NOT NULL` constraints):

```sql
CREATE TABLE Reservation(
  id          NUMBER(12,0)
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              CONSTRAINT pk_reservation PRIMARY KEY,
  Cust_Nbr    VARCHAR2(14)
              NOT NULL,
  Flight_Nbr  VARCHAR2(15)
              NOT NULL,
  Flight_Date DATE
              NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_Reservation_Cust_Nbr
    FOREIGN KEY (Cust_Nbr) REFERENCES Customer (Cust_Nbr),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Sched_Flight_Flight_Data
    FOREIGN KEY (Flight_Nbr, Flight_Date) REFERENCES Shed_Flight ( Flight_nbr, flight_date )
);
```

Comment: For Shed_Flight do you  have a recommendation on how to able to fix that flawed part of the data model? My Professor hasn't been the best at helping us this semester it has been a lot more of self-teaching. @MTO

Comment: This all helped out a lot! Thank you for your time and explanations of everything. @MTO